# Excel 2010 Dax Onhand Quantity Vs. Last Date Qty

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

Ive spent the last 2 days trying to get this, and I really just need a few pointers. Im using Excel 2010 w/ Power Pivot and calculating inventories. I am trying to get the amount sold between 2 dates. I recorded the quantity on hand if the item was in stock.

```
Item #  Day         Date        Qty
Black   Thursday    11/6/2014   2
Blue    Thursday    11/6/2014   3
Green   Thursday    11/6/2014   3
Black   Friday      11/7/2014   2
Green   Friday      11/7/2014   2
Black   Monday      11/10/2014  3
Blue    Monday      11/10/2014  4
Green   Monday      11/10/2014  3
```

Is there a way to do this in dax? I may have to go back and calculate the differences for each record in excel, but Id like to avoid that if possible.

Somethings that have made this hard for me.

1) I only record the inventory Mon-Fri. I am not sure this will always be the case so i'd like to avoid a dependency on this being only weekdays.
2) When there is none in stock, I dont have a record for that day

Ive tried, CALCULATE with dateadd and it gave me results nearly right, but it ended up filtering out some of the results. Really was odd, but almost right.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Bryan, this may not totally answer your question as there are a couple of things that aren't totally clear to me but it should give you a start and I'm happy to expand my answer if you provide further info.

One 'pattern' you can use involves the TOPN function which when used with the parameter n=1 can return the earliest or latest value from a table that it sorts by dates and can be filtered to be earlier/later than dates specified.

For this example I am using a 'disconnected' date table from which the user would select the two dates required in a slicer or report filter:

```
=
CALCULATE (
  SUM ( inventory[Qty] ),
  TOPN (
    1,
    FILTER ( inventory, inventory[Date] <= MAX ( dates[Date] ) ),
    inventory[Date],
    0
       )
          )
```

In this case the TOPN returns a single row table of the latest date earlier than or equal to the latest date provided. The 1st argument in the TOPN specifies the number of rows, the second the table to use, the 3rd the column to sort on and the 4th says to sort descending.

From here it is straightforward to adapt this for a second measure that finds the value for the latest date before or equal to the earliest date selected (i.e. swap MIN for MAX in MAX(dates[Date])).

Hope this helps.
Jacob

*prettified using daxformatter.com

Comment: Jacob, awesome! I have been using various hacks with calculated columns to make sure I get single row value... Didn't realize TOPN could be used in this way. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers Petr, TOPN FTW!!